# I used “data-target” to keep the active link style. How to maintain style even when moving pages from an active link?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm re-uploading to get help.

Referring to the answer of another question, I wrote the code to preserve the style when the link is activated using "data-target". But the style disappears when moving to the next page in the active link. For example, if the original link is "link/sub01.html" but changes to "link/sub01.html&page=2", the style is lost. I want the style to be maintained whenever there is a "data-target" value in the link. But I'm not familiar with the script yet, so I don't know where to fix it. Please help me.

I didn't speak English, so I used a translator. So the sentence may not be smooth. Sorry!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location;
    $('#CateList .CateBox li a[href="' + 'data-target' + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('#CateList .CateBox li a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .CateBox {
        position: relative;
    }

    .CateBox:after {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }

    .CateBox li {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 180px;
        height: 34px;
        float: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .CateBox li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: all .35s;
    }

    .CateBox li:hover {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .CateBox li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .CateBox li.active {
        background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    }

    .CateBox li.active a {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>


<div id="CateList">
    <ul class="CateBox">
        <li data-target="index"><a href="index.html">MAIN</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub01"><a href="sub01.html">SUB01</a></li>
        <li data-target="sub02"><a href="sub02.html">SUB02</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're switching between pages, you have to store the value somewhere like URL param/session storage/localstorage etc

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code... it looks like it may be due to parameters/query string on your URL.

Use `href.split('?')[0]` to only test the URL without the query string.

Furthermore, i'd recommend a simpler method:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/" title="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/Contact/" title="">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
// Active nav state
let mainNav = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');

for (let i = 0; i < mainNav.length; i++) {
    if (mainNav[i].href.split('?')[0] === window.location.href.split('?')[0]) {
        mainNav[i].classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

Vanilla JS, but reckon you should be able to convert to jquery simply enough :)